# Efficiency of Nginx Directory Index Listing

Tags: php, performance, nginx, indexing

I want to display all files in a directory as a json file on a http request most efficiently. As I always want to build websites scalable I was wondering what method is the most efficient and why:

1. Using Nginx Directory Index Listing (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html)
2. Searching PHP to scan through the folder and formatting it as a json

Alternatively I could just use a static json file which is updated after a certain amount of time using a script, although I would prefer one of the two methods mentioned above for maintainability reasons.

I couldn't find anything online about how efficient each method is or how to test the efficiency myself, that's why I am asking on here.

Comment: It depends on the size of your file list, however Nginx autoindex should be the fastest solution. You can also apply cache on the top of that if you really care about the speed.

Comment: @VisioN There are about 5-20 files in a directory, it probably doesn't make a difference whether they are files or directories, as the search isn't recursive if I am right here. Is there any amount of files where I should switch to a different folder structure/different method?

Comment: Probably not. For 5-20 files you shouldn't worry. Even if it's 10000, Nginx solution will be more than enough. It will be hard to beat autoindex module performance, as you don't need to upstream your request to another service to do the same job.